# What are best practices or strategies to securely store sensitive files locally in Flutter development?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm working on an app where I download sensitive files from an API and want to store them locally. However, I need to ensure these files are only accessible within my app and not by other apps or users. I've tried encryption, but it seems to slow down file access significantly.

What are some best practices or strategies to securely store these files locally while maintaining reasonable access speed within my app? I'm specifically looking for techniques that prevent external access and ensure the files are only usable within the confines of my application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this package: [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)

It is a kind of Shared Preferences, but it extremely encrypts the data. So, that data won't be accessible outside your app.

It is a well-known & verified package.

Metadata says: Flutter Secure Storage provides API to store data in secure storage. Keychain is used in iOS, KeyStore based solution is used in Android.

Comment: but flutter_secure_storage dont storge file